# Direct SSH connections between Jelastic containers

Tags: ssh, jelastic

I'm not planning to use the SSH connection outside of the Jelastic platform and [Direct Access to the Container](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access#direct-access) solution isn't covered my case.

Just I need directly connecting between my environments without using any additional gateways.
In the [Jelastic docs](https://docs.jelastic.com/) I cannot find any information about my case. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are some details about this case here: http://kb.layershift.com/ssh-jelastic-nodes

In summary, you can establish an SSH connection between Jelastic nodes via the SSH gateway, but if you want to establish a **direct** SSH connection it needs firewall adjustments (to open SSH access from different sources) and of course the appropriate SSH key added to authorized_keys file.

Due to the managed nature of Jelastic nodes, this needs assistance from your hosting provider - so please contact your hosting provider's support to get it configured.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You should use the [SSH Access to a Jelastic Account](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access#account-access) once for configuring SSH connections between your containers.

Let's configure your containers (I show you how to configure one connection, and you can use this instruction for other by analogy):

1. Enter into the container 1 using [SSH Access](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access).
2. Generate SSH Key:

   `apache@node51989-env-6759653 ~ $ ssh-keygen 
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa): 
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
   Enter same passphrase again: 
   Your identification has been saved in /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.`
3. Copy content from ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file.

   `apache@node51989-env-6759653 ~ $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDVNYjvkfj6mhjyhbkiNisDFxksG7IoAMkUYNpuqMz4afutNLcnZwkjAar3WZ/2892CR9Y3PiUUDLJKEg1OavZYpc63Fw6qGSQBFdn/r1n7mkZMIF1k0JUdFleKxhUyoxoc4jsSgIu2zr2738K2Mkx9C6oAK3DyGmezXe+g6J/kg0LHA9bqYPfLeRriC6N3e4FYBqHwBD5Fv7yu/RO9K6GzUP9PAhjNxlTrR6XYLdB37wmICZujlLM2VdADQrAHYbXIx3qswJIDrMygJ9VDs42YEiXP1YKTftqtueXbLHPMl0tb0EwCDCSQtCa0o9eHd3K4sJ3aIvW3Fm0oahP8SlJr apache@node51989-env-6759653.jelastic`
4. Enter into container 2 using [Jelastic SSH Gate](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access) Access.
5. Paste copied public key from container 1 into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file in container 2.

   `nginx@node51990-env-9925621 ~ $ echo 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDVNYjvkfj6mhjyhbkiNisDFxksG7IoAMkUYNpuqMz4afutNLcnZwkjAar3WZ/2892CR9Y3PiUUDLJKEg1OavZYpc63Fw6qGSQBFdn/r1n7mkZMIF1k0JUdFleKxhUyoxoc4jsSgIu2zr2738K2Mkx9C6oAK3DyGmezXe+g6J/kg0LHA9bqYPfLeRriC6N3e4FYBqHwBD5Fv7yu/RO9K6GzUP9PAhjNxlTrR6XYLdB37wmICZujlLM2VdADQrAHYbXIx3qswJIDrMygJ9VDs42YEiXP1YKTftqtueXbLHPMl0tb0EwCDCSQtCa0o9eHd3K4sJ3aIvW3Fm0oahP8SlJr apache@node51989-env-6759653.jelastic' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
6. Allow SSH connection from container 2 by editing /etc/sysconfig/iptables-custom file in the container 1. ([Custom Firewall Rules for Containers](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-firewall)).

`*filter
    :INPUT DROP [0:0]
    :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    -I INPUT -s <internal ip> -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT`

7. Restart firewall into the 2nd container.

   `nginx@node51990-env-9925621 ~ $ sudo /usr/bin/jem firewall fwstart`
8. Establis direct SSH connection.

   `ssh jelastic@<internal ip>`
9. Enjoy.